# gdal_rasterize using a "string" as src_datasource

Tags: raster, gdal

I would like to use a string as src_datasource for gdal_rasterize program.

Is it possible to use something like a WKT definition to translate a single point to a raster?

Something like:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -l mask "POINT(6 10)" work.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to write a CSV file, e.g. `point.csv`:

```
id,WKTgeom
1,POINT(6 10)
```

and then an OGR VRT file, e.g. `point.vrt`:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="point">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="0">point.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcLayer>point</SrcLayer>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="WKT" field="WKTgeom"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Finally, you can execute something like:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -l point point.vrt work.tif
```

Note:
`work.tif` must exist before you run `gdal_rasterize` and have three bands.

Comment: Ciao Antonio,
I know I can use a CSV via a .vrt file, but I have another goal. I'm looking for a way to convert a single a pair of coordinates to a raster file, without the need to create other external files.
Probably it's not possible.
I think it's possible in GRASS.

Grazie mille

Comment: I think that it's not possible, because you should specify other properties of the raster file (SRS, GeoTransform, etc.). GDAL Virtual Format is the right way in this case.